# Implementing OpenID consumer details

Tags: php, openid

For OpenID smart mode, the specification uses a Diffie-Hellman key exchange. I'm wondering if the public and private keys can be reused (assuming they aren't compromised), or if they should be generated for every request. I'm using PHP's OpenSSL library (my code: `$key = openssl_pkey_new(array('private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_DH));`) to generate keys, and it's terribly slow (22 seconds on average to generate a key--very unacceptable for a website). If keys can't be reused, is there any faster way I can generate keys using OpenSSL? I'd rather not do it by hand due to dependencies on math libraries, etc.

EDIT: To be clear, I am looking for two things in an answer: Can I reuse Diffie-Hellman keys in OpenID association mode, and if not, is there a faster way to generate keys using OpenSSL than `openssl_pkey_new()`, since that is taking an exceptionally long time.

Comment: WOW, why don't you use an OpenID library, instead of doing OpenID transaction on you own?

Comment: Because a) none of the meet my needs and b) I don't like using things that I don't understand. The JanRain library is terribly designed and loads slowly on my setup--not to mention the fact that it doesn't support PHP 5.3.5 (which I will not compromise on). LightOpenID uses preg all over the place instead of the proper XML DOM methods, which irks me to no end (not to mention the fact that it _still_ doesn't support smart mode authentication). There are no libraries that support both PHP 5.3.5 and smart mode authentication.

Comment: Whats about the Zend Framework OpenID?
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.consumer.html

Comment: I thought about that, and that's where I got the idea to use OpenSSL, but it's too thoroughly embedded within the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff,

I want to start by supporting your decision to build this solution yourself.  I agree that the other solutions are (for the most part) weak in several areas.  I have not yet transitioned completely into PHP 5.3.5 but will be right on your heels.

Anyway, there are several answers to your question:

1. Yes, so long as you can ensure the the private & public keys are not compromised, you are fine to re-use them.  I am always a bit paranoid about this however myself, so I use a cron job to regenerate my keys every night and then use session tracking to make sure that I have no transaction that starts under the old key and finished under the new one...  This extra step (regeneration every 24 hours) is unnecessary, but may help to ease your worries.
2. No, it should not take 22 seconds to generate new keys.  My server takes between 3-5 seconds to create these (which I still feel is far too long, hence the cron job on the side when users are not affected/waiting.  You may want to take a look in your logs to see if there are any warnings.  There could be a problem with your openssl.cnf or some configuration within the server.  I suppose it could take that long if your server is severaly overtaxed for resources or you have an insanely slow processor.  You may check what is running in the background...maybe some runaway infinite loop is tying up your processor and ram?  Is a reboot an option?

Good luck!

Comment: Great! I was hoping I could use the same key, but I wasn't sure--I'm kind of paranoid when it comes to cryptography, not being an expert in it. I'll examine my server logs, but after talking with a friend who does server administration for a living, I suspect it's just a lack of entropy in /dev/urandom causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> OpenID smart mode

What is this OpenID smart mode?
If you are NOT talking about consuming openID, I guess you could stop reading(although I don't think you should be creating yet another OpenID-provider. Enough of them already)

---

.
I have never read the openid specifications(long/complicated read :$. I would like to read/learn it sometime), but when it takes 21 seconds to do OpenID authentication(?). Then I think you are doing something wrong. The [LightOpenID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid)(real simple library) library(consumer) does OpenID authentication in a split second. I have created [this library which wraps LightOpenID+openid selector](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-openid). You could see a demo hosted on [my hosting](http://westerveld.name/php-openid/).

Comment: OpenID smart mode is where you associate with the provider, rather than asking the provider to validate the signature. And I looked at (and based my consumer--yes, I'm making a consumer--on) LightOpenID, but it didn't meet my needs (specifically, it doesn't support association). To be clear: It doesn't take me 22 seconds to perform authentication; it takes 22 seconds for openssl to generate the DH key.

Comment: @Jeff Hubbard thanks for your information. I really like LightOpenID. I could do OpenID authentication without any hassle. That's good enough for me :P. P.S: I found this interesting link looking op association => http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/05/understanding-openid-association.html